# strict typealias in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to define a type to represent iso datetime string as received by my API. 
I want the safety that though the representation is string, any string cannot be assigned to it.
The compiler should catch these assignments so I can convert if applicable. 
So I want something simart to this in golang `type Time string`

Below code in TS is allowed, and I need to prevent the assignment `const time: Time = "..."`

```
type Time = string; 
const message: string = 'hello world';
const time: Time = message;
```

[typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKglgW2gXigZ2AJzgOwOYDcUAUAMYD2OGUSaaAhnhAFzpa55SoDkAFhABsB5KAHdymAQBNuBMpWrBELWMq40IdRhDlA)

### Edit 1:

With the article Json mentioned below, I could add safety that arbitrary string cannot pass to `Time` type, but the reverse is possible. no error at `const someType: number = fourthOfJuly;`

```
enum DateStrBrand { }
export type DateStr = string & DateStrBrand;

const fourthOfJuly = toDateStr('2017-07-04');
const someType: string = fourthOfJuly;


function checkValidDateStr(str: string): str is DateStr {
  return str.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/) !== null;
}

export function toDateStr(date: string): DateStr {
  if (typeof date === 'string') {
    if (checkValidDateStr(date)) {
      return date;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Invalid date string: ${date}`);
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`Shouldn't get here (invalid toDateStr provided): ${date}`);
}
```

[typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=5&ssc=39&pln=5&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgF2AZQQJwEJriAJlAbygF8AoYADwAcB7NBKBATyuFkRXSgF4oBndAEsQAcygAydklSZseANylSAYxogBUAGY0w9ABYB5TQCkwAGyY9GNeNPQAKAOQAmAAwBGAOwBaVz9cALI4AlIqq6gx8NBDAACoswABcUOAQAEbAaFbaugiGJuZMikqaYCDKCIJqUMp6wMoA1gBqcGaCuLacaPYCaMm9wiLB-VyCfFJdhKRQUGjACLog-OgAdBCItfYA9AB6ADq4BAHE3gcEzidnFwAkW8FQAITcvOBmZopk5NR0DKXlldUEDYODJ7LgOCM0INhhMZFMZoJNFB7MxWDQkeCkDxnlBHANRCF4TMoIjkbV6s1Wu1OqDMcBgvcCNNiTM5gs0Es6YoWcQoMAzHw2EyWTM8mgaAB3FLAKUAUTQ4u6AAMAJIgABuVPwdOWUNEyWuBDpxCVoWZMzIFuZYsl0rlCro9iVyD0OjMuBAjgYInmUDqc2Rwk1bXwQJpXCo4vV7WAuBhhuNpo+QA)

Comment: "no error at `const someType: string = fourthOfJuly;`"  Is that a problem?  A `DateStr` is supposed to be a subtype of `string`, so it's desirable that you can assign a `DateStr` value to a `string` variable, but not vice versa.  What remains to be answered here?

Comment: There is no better compile-time support for what you're doing, since [regular expression validated string types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) are not part of the language.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for confirming. I made an edit to show that no error assigning to numbers, or any type. that's kind of worse :-)  `const someType: number = fourthOfJuly;`

Comment: Ah, the empty `enum` brand hasn't worked since TS3.6.  Instead maybe use a class with a private member like `class DateStrBrand { private dateStrBrand = "DateStr" }`

Comment: Or really anything from [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html)

Comment: thanks. I just got that page searching for `enum branding`. Didn't know that's a thing :-) will try out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @jcalz 's commnets from above, this is what I came up with the help of below resource.

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping

```
export interface DateStr extends String {
  ____dateStrBrand: string; // To prevent type errors
}

// Safety!
var fooId: Time = "..."; // error
fooId = "..." as any; // OK

// If you need the base string
var str: string;
str = fooId; // error
str = fooId as any; // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use a branded string and a typeguard to go along with it.

I'm glad I Googled before typing up a full explanation, though, because [Patrick Bacon has a great one already that you should check out](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/19/strongly-typed-date-string-typescript/).

Comment: thanks Jason. It is neat trick. Let's see anyone has a better idea to detect all error at compile time.

Comment: Do note that the empty `enum` brand has not worked since TS3.6; instead I'd probably use a class with a private member like `class DateStrBrand { private dateStrBrand = "DateStr" }`